# use ack-standalone.pl in VIM (WINDOWS)

Tags: perl, vim

OS: WINDOWS

perl: strawberry perl

vim: gvim74 (can run perl and ag by useing `:!perl` `：！ag`)

I use `strsf.vim` in VIM.
`strsf.vim` need ag or ack in background.
when I put `ag.exe` in system32 folder,`strsf.vim` works well.

the question is:
if I want to use ack instead of ag,
how can I make gvim know where the ack-standalone.pl is?

I have tried to put it in system32 , vim folder perl folder,neither worked

I also add perpath vim path to OS path ,nothing changed

I konw the `ack-standalone.pl` should run in perl , 
  and I tried to use `：！perl ack-standalone.pl` in vim，but some error occured as below

```
    C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /c (perl ack.pl)
    Can't open perl script "ack-standalone.pl": No such file or directory
    shell returned 2
    Hit any key to close this window...
```

when I use a bat file :

```
@"C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe" C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\ack-standalone.pl %*
```

it can works

what should I do if I want to use the `ack-standalone.pl` file in gvim ?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using a `ack.bat`file,and put it in `system32` folder which VIM can find it.
The content of `ack.bat` is

```
@"C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe" C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\ack %*
```

I don't think it is a good solution, so if anyone have a better one ,please tell me.